# I need to find multiple rows with iteration without using loop

Tags: sql-server

Let's say I have 2 tables.

**Users Table**

[image: User Table]

and Have one more table which defines hierarchy of user.

**hierarchy Table**

[image]

So as you can see:

**C** is a supervisor of **D**

**B** is a supervisor of **C**

**A** is a supervisor of **B**

So when I pass User D, then it should return all the supervisor like A,B,C
same when I pass User C, then it should return all the supervisor like A,B

What I tried.

```
Create table Users
 (
 Id int primary key identity (1,1),
 Name varchar(1), 
 )

 Insert into Users values ('A')
 Insert into Users values ('B')
 Insert into Users values ('C')
 Insert into Users values ('D')

 Create table Hierarchy
 (
 Id int primary key identity (1,1),
 EmployeeId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Users(Id),
 SupervisorId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Users(Id)
 )

 Insert into Hierarchy values (4,3)
 Insert into Hierarchy values (3,2)
 Insert into Hierarchy values (2,1)
 
 select * from Users
 select * from Hierarchy

 with HierarchyData as  
 (  
 select mbh.* from Hierarchy mbh where mbh.EmployeeId = 4  
 union all  
 select mbh.* from Hierarchy mbh  
 join Hierarchy on mbh.SupervisorId = Hierarchy.EmployeeId  
 where mbh.EmployeeId <> 4  
 )

 select e.Name as EmpName, s.Name as SupervisorName from HierarchyData h
 join Users e on h.EmployeeId = e.Id
 join Users s on h.SupervisorId = s.Id
```

But I am getting only one level data.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Pet peeve, but `;` is a statement **terminator**; it goes at the end of *all* your statements, not the beginning of statements that require the **previous** statement to be properly terminated.

Comment: We can't run your sample query with sample data in images, please add sample data as text, preferably as create/insert statements, see [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [Do not paste images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). As someone with over 1k repuation you should already know to do so.

Comment: @Stu I have added script as well.

Answer (score 0):

@Vishal as per my understanding written query for you can you please check it's working or not?

here I used `LEFT JOIN` you can go with `INNER JOIN`

If you go with `LEFT JOIN` as per your example `A` not have any `supervisor` so the record can be empty.

If you go with `INNER JOIN` as per your example you got only the `B, C, D` record.

Please check the below test query.

```
DECLARE @User TABLE
(
    UserID INT,
    UserName NVARCHAR(50)
)

DECLARE @EmployeeTable TABLE
(
    ID INT,
    EmployeeID INT,
    supervisorID INT
)

INSERT INTO @User VALUES(1,'A'),
(2,'B'),
(3,'C'),
(4,'D')

INSERT INTO @EmployeeTable VALUES
(1,4,3),
(2,3,2),
(3,2,1)
SELECT [U].[UserName] [EmployeeName],
[ET].[EmployeeID],
[ET].[SupervisorID],[ST].[SupervisorName]
FROM @User [U]
LEFT JOIN @EmployeeTable [ET] 
ON [U].[UserID] = [ET].[EmployeeID]
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT [U].UserName [SupervisorName] ,[ST].* FROM @User [U]
    INNER JOIN @EmployeeTable [ST]
    ON [ST].[supervisorID] = [U].[UserID]
) [ST]
ON [ST].[supervisorID] = [ET].[supervisorID]
```

> Left join query result

[image: Left join result]

> Inner join query result

[image]

let me know if I can help more :).

Comment: No you are returning all data, where I need list of all supervisor above that user for particular selected user

Comment: Okay, @Vishalmodi,
Probably we need to use `user-defined function` because it's complex logic.